# Why does the alert box show twice in this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Here is some simple code to demonstrate the "afterrender" functionality of knockout template. When I click on the button, the alert box shows up twice, while it is supposed to show up only once.

You can find the entire code below. Any idea of why the alert box shows up twice?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div data-bind="component: {name : 'foo-component', params: {onLoad: fooLoadedCallback}}"></div>

<!--foo-component params="onLoad: fooLoadedCallback"></foo-component-->


<script type="text/javascript">
ko.components.register('foo-component', {
    //inner view model, only for this component in the template below.
    viewModel: function(params) {
        return {
            status: ko.observable('Constructed'),

            //this is called only after the template is rendered. This is called due to a statement in template.
            componentLoaded: function () {

                if (params.onLoad) {
                    params.onLoad(this);
                }
                $('button').click(function(){
                    alert("Rendered.");
                });

            }
        };
    },
    template: '<h1>Hello</h1><br><button>Click me</button><br><span data-bind="text: status">Template</span>'
       +'<span data-bind="template: { afterRender: componentLoaded() }"></span>',
});

//outer view model, for the div element.
var outerViewModel = {
    fooLoadedCallback: function(viewModel) {
        viewModel.status('Rendered!');
    },
};

ko.applyBindings(outerViewModel);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i quess you have 2 of foo-component on your page, i think you should use   <button data-bind="click: nameOfFunction_from_viewModel"... like it is shown here http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-overview.html

Comment: The second foo-component is commented out, and I actually deleted it when I tested. As for the button, I know that syntax; my goal is to test the afterrenderer. Note that my question is not about how to use button; it's about why the alert box shows up twice.

Comment: Sorry i scrolled too quick so i didn't see any code above ko.components... anyway can you confirm that componentLoaded is only called once?

Comment: ah, when I load the page, componentLoaded is called twice. Why? I put an alert right above if(params) ... and that alert shows up twice.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting two alerts because your `componentLoaded` method is being called twice, attaching multiple listeners to the button.

I believe that your problem lies in the `<span data-bind="template: { afterRender: componentLoaded() }"></span>` part.

If you change the `template` with the `with` for example, your code works fine. There's an example:

```
template: '<h1>Hello</h1><br><button>Click me</button>'
+ '<br><span data-bind="text: status">Template</span>'
+ '<span data-bind="with: { afterRender: componentLoaded() }"></span>'
```

However, keep in mind that i've never used Knockout and can't tell your if that's the right thing to do. I'm just pointing out what's happening.

Comment: Indeed, componentLoaded  method is called twice. Any idea how to fix it? Not sure how to change the "template" with the "with", as you said.

Comment: try `<span data-bind="with: { afterRender: componentLoaded() }"></span>`

Comment: oh, that fixes it! Great. Please edit your answer so I can mark it as "answer".

Comment: I wouldn't go as far as calling it an answer. It looks more like a workaround than an answer to me. Maybe we better wait for someone that has some experience with the framework.

Comment: `with` is doing something completely different here. Pretty sure it's only working by pure coincidence. It must be creating just enough of a delay to allow the view model to be created first but I wouldn't rely on it.

Comment: @Romulo Try replacing `afterRender` with `blah`. Does it still "work"?

Comment: @CrimsonChris i haven't came up with the word `with` or the method `afterRender` myself. I´ve found it on [Knockout documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-syntax.html). Apparently Knockout always call the afterRender for the specified bindings (i´ve tested everyone in the **Controlling text and appearance** section. There's no point in trying to force Knockout to invoke a random method like `blah`.

Comment: @Romulo The `with` binding is *very* different from the `template` binding.

Comment: @CrimsonChris there's no doubt about it. And looking at the original question, the template binding is not the answer also. There's no definition of a template to be called. The point is, apparently every binding calls the `afterRender` method, and for that reason mostly will make the example work, even though they are not the optimal choice.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90483/discussion-between-romulo-and-crimsonchris).

Answer (score 2):

`afterRender` is always called twice when a component is loaded asynchronously. Once for the placeholder element and again for the real thing. Use something like [once](http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-once) to prevent it from being called twice or make `componentLoaded` safe to be called multiple times.

Also, `$('button')` will give you every button currently in the DOM. If you have multiple it will add that click to all of them.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed it using "with" instead of "template". I have an unrelated question though: For a third-party component, how do I state afterrenderer? For now, for "my own" component, I can modify the template by adding the span to it, like above. But for some third-party component, I am not supposed to change its code, then how do I allw afterrenderer?

Comment: @Simo Don't use `with` in place of `template`. They are completely different.

Comment: @Simo So you can't modify the source to add an `afterRender`? Can you create the view model in the parent and then pass it into the component?

Comment: No, I am not supposed to change the lib. So, the thing is I have nested components, one inside another. The inner component is bound to data retrieved through ajax, so it is loaded a little while after the outer component. As a result, when I use jquery in $(document).ready .... to apply $('button').click to the button in the inner component. And the result is, NOTHING happens when I click on the button. If the button is out of the inner component, then it works. So my guess is $(document).ready applies even before the inner component finishes rendering.

Comment: @Simo You are correct. One of the reasons why you shouldn't be modifying the DOM using jQuery when using Knockout.

Comment: Modifying a component externally through the DOM is very against how Knockout is supposed to be used. It seems like in this particular case you may just need to put in some sort of artificial delay in order to get it to work.

Comment: Ideally the component would have a callback that gets executed after its contents has finished loading.

Comment: Is there any work around, for example,  by not using jquery? I posted this separate question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32750577/knockout-nested-components-document-ready-runs-before-nest-component-i

Answer (score 0):

Just put your `componentLoaded()` inside a `function` like

```
 template: '<h1>Hello</h1><br><button>Click me</button><br><span data-bind="text: status">Template</span>'
       +'<span data-bind="template: { afterRender: function(){componentLoaded()} }"></span>'
```